# AJAX document.getElementById().innerHTML problem with IE?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, getelementbyid

Before someone said that I did not read I may say that I read almost everything linked with my question. But I couldn't find my answer.
So, I have a simple AJAX script that loads my external file inside predefined div. This is the code of those script:

```
    function loadTwitter()
  {
  var xmlHttp;
  try
    {
    // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  catch (e)
    {
    // Internet Explorer
    try
      {
      xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }
    catch (e)
      {
      try
        {
        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
      catch (e)
        {
        alert("Your Browser Don't Support AJAX!");
        return false;
        }
      }
    }
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
        {
        document.getElementById("column_twitter").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlHttp.open("GET","../includes/home/twitter.php",true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
  }
```

It works just fine in everyone browser that I test (FF, Opera, Chrome, Safari), but inside IE7 don't want to inject my external php file into predefined div. It always stays the default text that I wright inside div... 
And I think that the problem is in this row:

```
document.getElementById("column_twitter").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
```

So, any suggestions how to fix this for IE (7 and above)?

Comment: Downvote removed. This question was down-voted, why? Seriously, why?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen that style of brace-indentation used before, until now.

Comment: Probably because my awful english :))
No, seriously, my questions are simple and maybe even dumb for most of specialists. And I am sorry for that...

Comment: Despite the odd and inconsistent indents, your example works for me in IE6 and IE7. I think the problem is in some other part of the script or the PHP, that you haven't posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you'd be better off using a javascript framework such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) that allows you to concentrate on getting your features implemented rather than browser compatibility and low level network interaction.  Using jQuery you could simply do:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$.get( '../includes/home/twitter.php', function(data) {
     $('#column_twitter').html( data );
});

</script>
```

Comment: +1'd, even shorter would be $('#column_twitter').load('../includes/home/twitter.php');

Comment: @karim79 - yeah, that's definitely shorter.  I hardly ever use load though, because usually I'm passing data back or I want to do something more complicated after I get the data.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question, but I ran into a similar thing today and I wanted to post it out for others in case you experience this issue. This is likely being caused by your "column_twitter" tag being embedded in multiple DIV statements or in a table. IE7 doesn't like this for some reason.

Good Luck!